# BST: how to define `insert` in terms of catamorphic fold?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-search-tree, catamorphism

I have a typical binary search tree data type:

```
data Tree a
  = Empty
  | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

and a catamorphism

```
foldt :: b -> (a -> b -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldt empty _ Empty = empty
foldt empty branch (Branch a l r) = branch a (foldt empty branch l) (foldt empty branch r)
```

I tried to define an insert function using `foldt` and got some interesting results:

```
insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x = foldt (single x) insertb
  where insertb a left right
          | x == a = Branch x left right
          | x < a = Branch a (insert x left) right
          | x > a = Branch a left (insert x right)
```

```
ghci> mytree = insert 2 (Branch 3 Empty Empty)  
ghci> mytree
Branch 3 (Branch 2 (Branch 2 Empty Empty) (Branch 2 Empty Empty)) (Branch 2 Empty Empty)
ghci>
```

Of course, a traditional insert method behaves as expected:

```
insert' :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert' x Empty = single x
insert' x (Branch a left right)
  | x == a = Branch x left right
  | x < a = Branch a (insert' x left) right
  | x > a = Branch a left (insert' x right)
```

```
ghci> mytree2 = insert' 2 (Branch 3 Empty Empty)
ghci> mytree2
Branch 3 (Branch 2 Empty Empty) Empty
ghci>
```

Is there a way to define `insert` in terms of `foldt`, or am I barking up the wrong tree (*ha*) here?

Comment: Maybe it's possible with `cata`, I'm not sure. But it's easy with `para`, which seems perfect for this use case.

Comment: Hint: the `foldt empty branch` application shouldn't produce the tree directly. It could produce a *function* `Maybe a -> Tree a`, and I suspect could alternatively produce a pair of trees, one of which has the insertion performed and the other of which does not. A paramorphism would certainly be better from an efficiency standpoint.

Comment: Note that when using things like `foldt` you're generally trying to *avoid* explicit recursion elsewhere. So those `insert` calls in `insertb` are a bit of a red flag.

Comment: @amalloy `cata` and `para` are of equivalent power. But yes, they're definitely not of equivalent convenience.

Comment: @Carl, nor equivalent performance. `para` wins you a lot of sharing.

Answer (score 4):

Let's define a function

```
insertMaybe :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a -> Tree a
```

This function takes a tree, and maybe an element. In the `Just` case, the element is inserted. In the `Nothing` case, the tree is returned unchanged. So then we can define

```
insert a t = insertMaybe t (Just a)
```

Now:

```
insertMaybe :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a -> Tree a
insertMaybe = foldt leaf branch
  where
    leaf (Just new) = ?
    leaf Nothing = ?

    branch a l r Nothing = ?
    branch a l r (Just new)
      | ... = ?
      ...
```

---

Alternatively:

```
data Ins a = Ins
  { inserted :: Tree a
  , notInserted :: Tree a }

insert a t = inserted (insertAndNot a t)

-- Return the tree with the 
-- element inserted, and also unchanged.
insertAndNot :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Ins a
insertAndNot new = foldt leaf branch
  where
    leaf = Ins ? ?
    branch a ~(Ins li lni) ~(Ins ri rni)
      | ... = Ins ? ?
      ...
```

#### Paramorphism

The above solutions have a major efficiency problem: they completely rebuild the tree structure just to insert an element. As amalloy suggested, we can fix that by replacing `foldt` (a catamorphism) by `parat` (a paramorphism). `parat` gives the `branch` function access to *both* the recursively modified and the unmodified subtrees.

```
parat :: b -> (a -> (Tree a, b) -> (Tree a, b) -> b) -> Tree a -> b
parat leaf _branch Empty = leaf
parat leaf branch (Branch a l r) =
  branch a
         (l, parat leaf branch l)
         (r, parat leaf branch r)
```

Conveniently, it's also slightly *easier* to define `insert` using `parat`. Can you see how? This ends up being an efficient version of the "alternative" way I suggested for using `foldt`.

Comment: Ah I think I see it now! I'll update my post. Please let me know if there's a better way to write it.

Comment: Also I noticed that recursive calls within `parat` seemed a bit more natural than in `foldt`. Are paramorphisms suited more for this recursion or is it still a weird pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to dfeuer and amalloy for the tips on paramorphisms, TIL!

Given a paramorphism for the Tree data type:

```
parat :: b -> (a -> (Tree a, b) -> (Tree a, b) -> b) -> Tree a -> b
parat empty _ Empty = empty
parat empty branch (Branch a l r) =
  branch a
         (l, parat leaf branch l)
         (r, parat leaf branch r)
```

we can write an insert function as:

```
insert :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x = parat (single x) branch
  where branch a (l, l') (r, r')
          | x == a = Branch x l r
          | x < a = Branch a l' r
          | x > a = Branch a l r'
```

```
ghci> mytree = insert 2 (Branch 3 Empty Empty)
ghci> mytree
Branch 3 (Branch 2 Empty Empty) Empty
ghci>
```

testing a bigger tree...

```
import Data.Function

mytree :: Tree Integer
mytree = (Branch 3 Empty Empty) & insert 2 & insert 4 & insert 6 & insert 5 & insert 10

inorder :: Tree a -> [a]
inorder = foldt [] (\a l r -> l ++ [a] ++ r)
```

```
ghci> mytree
Branch 3 (Branch 2 Empty Empty) (Branch 4 Empty (Branch 6 (Branch 5 Empty Empty) (Branch 10 Empty Empty)))
ghci> inorder mytree
[2,3,4,5,6,10]
ghci>
```

Comment: No, you really shouldn't be using `insert` in the definition of `branch`. Remember what `parat` is passing in! `parat` is doing the recursion for you; you didn't need any more recursion.

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, it's just `l' r` and `l r'` respectively, right? My brain hurts after that one.

Comment: Yes, now you're getting the hang of it! Just for fun, I suggest you attempt my first two approaches (using `foldt`). Once you've done that, also for fun, use my *second* approach to implement an inefficient version of `parat` using `foldt`.

Comment: @j_maes54 You could also try using an "apomorphism" which is the unfolding version of a paramorphism. It starts from a seed (which I think would consist in the original tree plus the value to insert) and generates a new tree. The apo would let you return a subtree immediately as a result, if you knew that you weren't going to modify that branch. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.2.2.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:apo The signature would be something like `apo ::  (b -> Maybe (a, Either (Tree a) b, Either (Tree a) b)) ->  b -> Tree a`. A `Nothing` means produce `Empty`

Comment: @danidiaz, yes, unfolding is often an option. Might be good to learn about anamorphisms before apomorphisms.